# Simplifying a Regex expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am not very familiar with Regex and have been trying to reduce the below problems to a single  expression. The first example will always have `{Container:}` and the second will always have `{Container: randomname Running · random# GPM · randomitem}` with `Running` also possibly being `Offline` and `Stopped`.

**Problem 1:**

Expression I want to narrow down:
`{Container: Jake}`

Desired Regex.replace outcome: `“Jake”`

Current Solution:

```
String test = {Container: Jake}
Regex.Replace(test.ToString(), "{Container:", "");
Regex.Replace(test,"}", "");
```

**Problem 2**

Expression I want to narrow down: 
`{Container: Jake Running · 56 GPM · Beans}`

Desired Regex.replace outcome: `“Running”`

```
String test = {Container: Jake Running · 56 GPM · Beans }
Regex.Replace(test.ToString(), "{Container:", ""); //Gets rid of specific expression
Regex.Replace(test,"}", ""); //Gets rid of only } curly bracket
Regex.Replace(app_values.all_devices_status, @"\b(?!Running|Stopped)\b\w*",""); //gets ride of everything except “Running  ·  ·”  Problem is this expression leaves in dots 
Regex.Replace(app_values.all_devices_status, "[^a-zA-Z]+", ""); //gets only the alphabet letters
```

Comment: I just throw this out here down at your feet without even a sliver of an explanation: `var result = Regex.Replace(s1, @"{Container:\s+(?i)(?:([a-z]+)|[a-z]+\s+([a-z]+)\s.+)}", "$1");`. If somebody wants to write an answer with explanation based on this regex replacement, please feel free and invited ;-) (Instead of replacement, you could also just match and take the value of captured group; whatever floats your boat ;-) )

Comment: FYI If you're doing a replace with just static text you don't need to use Regex you can just use `string.Replace` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options for both cases: Use lookarounds to get what you want in the full match or use a capture group to extract the result.

1. Using Lookarounds to capture everything between `{Container:`...`}`

   ```
   (?<={Container:\s).*?(?=})

   (?<={Container:\s\w+\s)\w+(?=\s.*?})
   ```

The 2nd pattern only works in the .NET regex engine that allows quantifier in lookarounds.

2. Using a capture group to extract the result

   ```
   {Container:\s(\S+)}

   {Container:\s\w+\s(\S+)\s.*?}
   ```

You can test it [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%7BContainer%3A%5Cs%5Cw%2B%5Cs%29%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3D%5Cs.*%3F%7D%29&i=%7BContainer%3A%20Jake%7D%0D%0A%7BContainer%3A%20randomname%20Running%20%C2%B7%20random%23%20GPM%20%C2%B7%20randomitem%7D) and check the explanation and generate C# code based on the pattern (even if it does not support the 2nd option above) [here](https://regex101.com/r/vwbJDk/1/).

Answer (score 0):

This expression,

```
{Container:\s*([^\s}]+).*
```

captures `Jake` ([demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/fGJeqq/1/)), and

```
{Container:.*?\s*([^\s]+)\s*·.*
```

might likely return `Running`.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/sorrvn/1/)

#### Example

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"{Container:.*?\s*([^\s]+)\s*·.*";
        string substitution = @"$1";
        string input = @"{Container: randomname Running · random# GPM · randomitem}
{Container: Jake Running · 56 GPM · Beans}
{Container: Jake-Some-other-name Running · 56 GPM · Beans}
{Container: Jake-Some-other-name     Running     · 56 GPM · Beans}";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

Comment: `[^\s]` could be substituted by `\S` 